# How do I get rid of error 403 while fetching an API using javascript in my Django application?

Tags: javascript, api, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am very new to javascript. I was working on a project, that I have to make a social-networking site using Django. There I have a like feature that will asynchronously update the like button to an unlike button and the number of liked users will also be updated without reloading the page. That is, I have to update the like button and number of likes using javascript fetch. I have trouble fetching that API, where I get error 403.[image]

I got the marked error while clicking on my like button. Here I am sharing my js code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    document.querySelector('#like').addEventListener('click', ()=> like_function('like'));
})

// let posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}";

let is_like = "{{is_like}}";
let num_like = "{{num_like}}";

function like_function(like){
    fetch(`/index/${posts_id}`,{
        method:"POST",
        body : JSON.stringify({
            "is_like" : is_like,
            "num_like" : num_like,
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Unike";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Like";
        }
    })
}
```

Also, I can't figure out why I am getting "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1". My Django views method generates JSON data. Here is the views function.

```
@login_required
def likepost(request,posts_id):
    posts = NewPost.objects.get(id = posts_id)
    is_like = False
    for like in posts.likepost.all():
        if like == request.user and request.method == "POST":
            is_like = True
            break
    
    if not is_like:
        posts.likepost.add(request.user)
    
    else:
        posts.likepost.remove(request.user)

    # serialize_obj = serializers.serialize("json",posts_id)
    
    return JsonResponse({
        "is_like" : is_like,
        "num_like" : posts.likepost.count()
    },safe=False)
```

Here I am sharing my like button in the Django template (HTML file):

```html
<form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id = "like" class="btn btn-link">Like</button>
    </form>

    <small id="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
    {% block script %} 
        <script>
            let posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}";
        </script>
        <script src="{% static 'network/controller.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

And also I'm sharing my `urls.py` file here if you need it.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("profile/<int:id>",views.profilepage,name="profile"),
    path("profile/<int:id>/following/addfollower",views.followersPeople,name="addfollower"),
    path("profile/<int:id>/following/removefollower",views.followersRemove,name="removefollower"),
    path("postform", views.createpost, name="postform"),
    path("editform/<int:id>",views.editpost,name="editpost"),
    path("following",views.followerspost,name="following"),
    path("index/<int:posts_id>",views.likepost, name="likepost"),
    path("postpage/<int:id>",views.view_post,name="postpage"),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I can't understand where I've made the mistake or which one I've skipped. Here is what I am actually happening in my project. https://youtu.be/lPGX9RhcSpU
I want my javascript function will take the JSON data generated by Django views `likepost` method and will take me back to my homepage by updating the number of likes and the like button to an unlike-button asynchronously without reloading the homepage.

So, what should I do now?